# How to star-rate "Apple Music" files in iTunes on OS X

Tags: macos, itunes, music, ratings

I like rating music as I'm listening to it so I can find my favorite stuff easily later.  But I'm now an Apple Music subscriber and listening to a LOT of new music that the service has found for me.  Unfortunately those streamed songs, don't appear to allow star ratings!  They only allow a "heart" rating.

But here's the weird part.  I discovered that you CAN see the star ratings if you right-click an Apple Music song and Get Info on it.  BUT, you cannot actually edit the rating, it's disabled.

But here's the *weirder* part.  If you select MULTIPLE files at once (at least two), then you CAN edit the star ratings!

So, is this a bug?  An intended feature?  Is there some other way to actually star-rate a single Apple Music streamed song?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had several people ask for help with Apple Music and this has helped them - hopefully it's what you're looking for.

Stars are tracked in your music library - so if you are playing songs from the cloud - it's a bug if you can input stars for tracks that are not part of your actual library.

One you add a song/album to your library - the stars should be there for you to rate things.

Hearts are tracked in the cloud - so you should always be able to use that control whether you are streaming a radio song that's not even in Apple Music for download, streaming Apple Music or playing a song that's in your library due to purchase, rip, or music addition.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I had surmised... which is why I was shocked to discover that I *could* actually star-rate items in the cloud, as long as I select more than one.  Clearly the capability exists... wish Apple would just enable it as it's extremely useful!  So then is there no way to star-rate a single song in the cloud?

Comment: @JonathanvanClute Not on any builds of iTunes I have access to. A screen shot of how precisely you managed the operation might help me suss out your specific operation.

Comment: A screenshot won't really show the steps, only the end result.  But the steps are simple - 1. Go to the 'New' tab in iTunes and select something from Apple Music.  2.  Select at least 2 songs 3.  Right-click one of them and choose Get Info 4.  Edit star ratings.

Comment: Aah - you aren't using the column browser but instead the dialog window to edit metadata. I didn't think of that +1

Comment: Yeah it was an accidental find, I was shocked to see the star ratings at all, and even more so that I could edit them, but ONLY with more than one selected!  So it obviously works, I wonder why Apple doesn't just plain let us star rate cloud music?  Seems like it would be useful for them too, they could aggregate all that crowd-sourced data and show it to people so we could all see what the greater world thinks of a given track.  Maybe it's coming in the future and this is evidence of a partial implementation?

Comment: Either that - or you've set up your music library to crash when the code sees stars for tracks that don't exist locally :(

Comment: BAH!  The stars all disappear as soon as you leave that screen to another of Apple Music content.  They do not persist when you return.  Drat.

Comment: Oh also another observation.  It's odd that this ratings feature doesn't work, because as soon as you add the song to your library - even leaving it on the cloud - you can rate it.  I guess they don't want to link the ratings to a specific person if that person doesn't feel it's worth having in their library.  But then why would you rate it if it wasn't?  Seems like Apple could build up a great crowdsourced ratings library if they allowed direct star ratings of tracks regardless of library status.  *shrug*

Answer (score -3):

it seems once you've downloaded the song you can give it a star rating

Comment: Your answer was already covered previously in the comments on the other answer.  The question was about how to star rate Apple Music songs, not local library songs.